# LinkedIn Authentication Auto Redirect with Code = null once AccessToken get deleted or revoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn oauth 2.0 api implementation and all went well to setup and retrieval of Access Token, but then i revoked the AccessToken after login in LinkedIn and also deleted the AccessToken i saved in my DB.

The idea is to give an option to Re-Authorize the account as given in point 1 below.

Once the request is made, one of the following occurs:

1. If the member has not previously accepted the application's permission request, or the grant has expired or been manually revoked by the member, the browser is redirected to LinkedIn's authorization screen as shown in the screenshot below. When the member completes the authorization process, the browser is redirected to the URL provided in the redirect_uri query parameter.
2. If there is a valid existing permission grant from the member, the authorization screen is bypassed and the member is immediately redirected to the URL provided in the redirect_uri query parameter.

What actually happen is that when ever i redirect user to the Authorization URL, it goes for **option 2** written above rather than **option 1**, and with a null Authorization Code. Below given is my Code on click of a button.

```
        var permissions = new string[] { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress", "w_member_social" }; 
         var authUrl = client.GetAuthorizationUrl(permissions,true);
        return new RedirectResult(authUrl.ToString());
```

and below given is the method that get called when LinkedIn callback redirect_uri

```
    public ActionResult LinkedInAuthentication(string code, string state)
    {
      //the code parameter is null here
    }
```

This should not be the behavior, please help.

Also can i know how to request for RefreshToken?

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh issue resolved, after a lot of search, i started reading complete linkedin documentation and found below given statement under integration > SignIn with LinkedIn rather under Authentication > Authorization Code Flow (3-legged OAuth) which actually explains each step of authentication. The link that explains this is

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context?trk=eml_mktg_gco_dev_api_comms#authenticating-members

> **Authenticating Members** 
>   New members logging in to your service for the first time will need to follow the Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 Guide. When requesting an authorization code in Step 2 of the OAuth 2.0 Guide, make sure to request the **r_liteprofile** and/or **r_emailaddress** scopes!

so changing

```
var permissions = new string[] { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress", "w_member_social" };
```

to

```
var permissions = new string[] { "r_liteprofile", "r_emailaddress"};
```

resolved the issue.

Hope someone else will be benefited to :)

Also if someone can help how to enable basicprofile and fullprofile features in app? That will be great.